# Get individual listbox item properties in tkinter using itemcget?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, listbox

I wrote the below code to bind event and do operations on individual listbox items.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
custom_list = tk.Listbox(root)
custom_list.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

def onselect_listitem(event):
    w = event.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    print(index, value, " color : ",custom_list.itemcget(index,'background'))
    custom_list.itemconfig(index, fg='gray', selectforeground="gray")

custom_list.bind('<Double-Button-1>', onselect_listitem)

for k in range(20):
    custom_list.insert(k, " --------- " + str(k))

root.mainloop()
```

I am having trouble using itemcget to get the background properties while itemconfig works properly. Everything else is working. Can someone tell me if there is something wrong? I am trying to obtain the current item background color via index of the item in the listbox. The part with custom_list.itemcget doesn't print anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [New Mexico tech Tkinter reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190525055058/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html):

> `.itemcget(index, option)`
>
> - Retrieves one of the option values for a specific line in the listbox. For option values, see `itemconfig` below. If the given option has not been set for the given line, the returned value will be an empty string.

So since you haven't set the `background` option, `itemcget` returns an empty string. You can see this working by changing the print to `custom_list.itemcget(index,'fg')`. The first time you doubleclick you get an empty sting because you haven't set it, the second time it prints `gray`.

Comment: Thanks! It works now! Just wondering if there is no default value that should be returned. Anyway, got it. Thanks a lot.